# Hibernate Optimistic Lock method

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I have an entity :

```
@Entity
public class Client {
  .....

    @Version
    @Column(name="OPTLOCK")
    private long version;
}
```

Now Optimistic lock is always working, now each method can throw a ObjectStaleStateException
BUT, if I want to make Optimistic just some certain method how can I do that ?
I have 10 methods in my Service that use my Client entity, but I want to make Optimistic just one method from 10.

Comment: [this](http://jeeva-paramasamy.blogspot.com/2012/10/disable-hibernate-optimistic-lock-for.html) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is, you want the locking feature to be used for specific service method.

As far as I know this is not possible.

If you go for pessimist locking you can explicitly pass lock mode.